# Passing value to Injectable extends class in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have one class like this, the problem i have is that **url** i should pass from other place

```
@Injectable()
export class SearchSimpleService extends SearchBaseService {
  protected searchUrl = `${url}/search/single`;
  constructor(http: HttpClient) {
    super(http);
  }
}
```

And my new class should look like this

```
@Injectable()
export class SearchSimpleService(url: string) extends SearchBaseService {
  protected searchUrl = `${url}/search/single`;
  constructor(http: HttpClient) {
    super(http);
  }
}
```

Even here I am doing wrong

```
export class SearchSimpleService extends SearchBaseService {
  protected searchUrl = `${url}/search/single`;
  constructor(http: HttpClient) {
    super(http);
  }
  searchUrlEnviroment(url: string) {
    return this.searchUrl = `${url}/search/single`;
  }
}
```

But **SearchSimpleService(url: string)** I dont think this is proper way and this is not working, can anybody help me about this thanks. I know my syntax is wrong but I dont know where even to start, thanks

Comment: I''m not entirely sure what you're trying to do here, since you've only shown the SimpleService. Is there a URL definied in the SearchBaseService that you want to retrieve in the SimpleService?

Answer (score 0):

It you want pass the url to the service constructor, you can use an [InjectionToken](https://angular.io/api/core/InjectionToken#injectiontoken), see [Dependency Providers](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-providers) and [Dependency Injection in Angular](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection#dependency-injection-in-angular) for more details. Once you've created the token, you should provide it somewhere, for example:

```js
// search_simple.service.ts

export const SEARCH_SIMPLE_URL = new InjectionToken('SearchSimpleService.url');

@Injectable()
export class SearchSimpleService extends SearchBaseService {
  constructor(
    private readonly http: HttpClient,
    @Inject(SEARCH_SIMPLE_URL) private readonly url: string
  ) {
    super(http);
  }
}
```

```js
// search_simple.component.ts

@Component({
  providers: [
    SearchSimpleService,
    { provide: SEARCH_SIMPLE_URL, useValue: "my/search/url" }
  ]
  ...
})
export class SearchSimpleComponent {
  constructor(
    private readonly searchService: SearchSimpleService
  ) { ... }
}
```

Comment: compiler.js:2430 Uncaught Error: Unexpected value 'undefined' declared

Comment: @MiomirDancevic Could you add more information about the error? Otherwise it's hard to figure out what is wrong. And it's better to add a code snippet too